# remove NSDictionary from NSArray in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsdictionary

I have an array like

```
(
                {
            "can_remove" = 0;
            date = "April 12, 2014";
            "date_created" = "12-04-2014 04:15:19";
            id = 18;
            "is_connected" = 0;
            name = "J J";
            status = first;
            time = "04:15 AM";
            "user_id" = 94;
        },
                {
            "can_remove" = 0;
            date = "April 12, 2014";
            "date_created" = "12-04-2014 02:55:02";
            id = 16;
            "is_connected" = 0;
            name = abc;
            status = "";
            time = "02:55 AM";
            "user_id" = 89;
        }
    );
```

**mean Array contains multiple Dictionary as an object**

**How can I delete any dictionary from this array?**

Help me to solve this....

Thanks....

Comment: what do you mean by "Any dictionary"?

Comment: It needs to be a NSMutableArray before you can modify what objects it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove objects from an array if it is `NSMutableArray`. You can create a mutable array from your existing `NSArray` by,

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArr = [currentArray mutableCopy];
```

Now a `NSMutableArray` has methods like `removeObjectAtIndex:` using which you can remove the dictionary at required index. Refer [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray%5fClass/Reference/Reference.html) for more methods and details.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove using NSArray for that you have to use NSMutableArray

NSMutableArray has methods like removeObjectAtIndex: using which you can remove the dictionary at required index. Refer documentation for more methods and details.

Answer (score 0):

To remove object from array 1st you need NSMutableArray and then you can use remove/add objects to it [doc here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray%5fClass/Reference/Reference.html)